# SQL Replication: Access snapshot folder is denied (SQL Server 2008)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, replication

When i created distributor, snapshot folder have share to network with this path:
\ComputerName\repldata

But when i use merge replication with pull method, this message was fired:

> > Source: mscorlib
>
> Target Site: Void WinIOError(Int32, System.String)
>
> Message: Access to the path 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\MSSQL12.SQL2014\MSSQL\repldata\unc\VLASERVER$SQL2014_TESTDB_TESTDB\20170208090120\'
>   is denied. Stack:     at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode,
>   String maybeFullPath)
>       at System.IO.Directory.InternalCreateDirectory(String fullPath, String path, Object dirSecurityObj, Boolean checkHost)
>       at System.IO.Directory.InternalCreateDirectoryHelper(String path, Boolean checkHost)
>       at Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.Utilities.CreateDirectoryWithExtendedErrorInformation(String
>   directory)
>       at Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.Snapshot.SnapshotProvider.CreateSnapshotFolders()
>       at Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.Snapshot.MergeSnapshotProvider.CreateSnapshotFolders()
>       at Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.Snapshot.SqlServerSnapshotProvider.GenerateSnapshot()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.SnapshotGenerationAgent.InternalRun() 
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.AgentCore.Run() (Source: mscorlib,
>   Error number: 0) Get help: http://help/0

Comment: Please help me!!!

Comment: "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL " is your snapshot location???

Answer (score 4):

You need to grant access to the snapshot folder to whatever account you are using for replication.  This can be a separate account or the account that runs your SQL Server.  Probably the easiest thing to do would be to just grant full access to "Everyone", see if that works, if it does then that's your problem and you just need to track down the account that replication is running as.

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide "Full Control" access to the snap shot folder for the account you are using for replication. Along with this, you have to configure distribution for the same server where your snap shot folder is created and the name of your distributor server should be same as the name of your SQL SERVER (sql server instance should be of the distributor server). This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The default location for the snapshot files is \\servername\C$...

Change it to target the share.

[Booksonline - Modify Snapshot Initialization Options for SQL Replication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/snapshot-options?view=sql-server-ver16)

[image]